# capitalize every word in an acronym (\acl command in the acro-package)

Tags: acronyms, capitalization, acro

I would like to have a command which capitalizes every word when I use an `\acl` command of the acro-package.

```
\DeclareAcronym{t}{short={t},long={this is a test}}
\capitalizingcommand{\acl{t}}
```

My desired output would be:

> This Is A Test

as far as i know the acro-package only supports the capitalization of the first word via `\Acl{t}`.

So far I tried the `\ecapitalisewords` command from the `mfirstuc`-package, but the expansion seems not to work and latex tries to capitalise the shortcut which results in an error.

This is my working or rather not working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{t}{short={t},long={this is a test}}
\begin{document}

\acl{t}
%\ecapitalisewords{\acl{t}}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly. However, you can define a macro which sets `long-format` to `\capitalisewords` in a group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{t}{short={t},long={this is a test}}

\newcommand*\accapitalizelong[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \acsetup{long-format=\capitalisewords}%
    #1%
  \endgroup  
}

\begin{document}

\acl{t}

\accapitalizelong{\acl{t}}

\acl{t}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you instead want to generally change the uppercasing behaviour of all the `\Ac...`  macros you can set the option `uc-cmd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{t}{short={t},long={this is a test}}

\acsetup{uc-cmd=\capitalisewords}

\begin{document}

\acl{t}

\Acl{t}

\end{document}
```

Of course you can also define a similar command like in my first suggestion to locally change uppercasing. Or even define a `\ACL`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{t}{short={t},long={this is a test}}

\NewDocumentCommand\ACL{sm}{%
  \begingroup
    \acsetup{uc-cmd=\capitalisewords}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\Acl*{#2}}{\Acl{#2}}%
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}

\acl{t}

\Acl{t}

\ACL{t}

\end{document}
```